# OpenOffice lost connection to MySQL on open cursor

Tags: mysql, openoffice.org, openoffice-base

Creating reports from OCS-NG Inventory using OpenOffice Base.

Because of poor functionality of OOOs Base source editor (it haven't even search facility!), I prefer to develop scripts in MySQL Workbench (both in Windows and in Linux). De-bugged script to be copied into OOO.

Until today all worked fine, including stored procedures and functions. Today I wrote another stored function utilizing data base cursor. On Workbench the script works just perfectly, producing usable results.

I copied script to Base and it failed with error 2013 "lost connection...". In WB the script execution takes about 3-4 seconds to return 348 rows on 4Mbit internet connection and even less on Gbit LAN., so timeouts aren't in charge.

Commenting out parts of stored function, I found that the failure occurs on `open cursor_name` statement. Well... I can copy-paste WB's script output into spreadsheet, but using all-in-one office package is more convenient.

Let's remind: the same script, calling the same function, does work in WB.

So, if anyone using OOO for accessing MySQL databases, may be you have solution? I asked Q's on OOO forums and asked for TS, but got no usable reply.

**edit:** Beginning of function

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `get_monitors`(gmhwid int(11)) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
declare MOV tinytext;
declare RetVal text;
declare NumOfMons, RowNum int;
# CURSOR-related variables
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare gmM, gmC, gmD, gmS tinytext charset utf8;
declare MonCursor cursor for select
    MANUFACTURER,CAPTION,DESCRIPTION,SERIAL 
    from ocsweb.monitors
    where ocsweb.monitors.hardware_id=gmhwid;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

# If there''s an overrider, use it and return
set MOV=(select Realmonitor from accinfo where hardware_id=gmhwid);
if ((MOV<>'') and (not isnull(MOV))) then
    return mov;
end if;

# how many monitors for this computer
set NumOfMons=(select count(*) from monitors where hardware_id=gmhwid);
set RowNum=0;
set RetVal='';
#set @sel:=(select MANUFACTURER,CAPTION,DESCRIPTION,SERIAL from monitors where monitors.hardware_id=gmhwid);
return '-';
open MonCursor;
```

Note two last lines. Fake return with a dash is kinda breakpoint. With it the function works in OOO, but produces no usabel result, of course. Then the main loop started:

```
lup: loop
    set MOV='';
    fetch MonCursor into gmM, gmC, gmD, gmS;
```

But execution will never reach the `lup:` label, if executing in OOO.

Comment: Are you able to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the stored function?

Comment: @JimK I can't put the OCS-NG's schema here, but the source of SP is really very simple. Asses it to question

Comment: I wrote a workaround procedure, which traverse monitors table without cursors, but I dislike such solutions